# How to resize a video to fit the size of image above it?

Tags: html, css, web

I'm trying to find a way to scale the video to fit the same width as my header photo.

How would I scale the video up to the same size as in the original website?
Here's the codepen; https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wZbjNw

For reference, I'm trying to mimic this website: https://jackwhiteiii.com/

```css
.jwlogo {
  max-width: 69%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 13px;
  image: no-repeat
}

.video {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 13px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="headerlogo">
    <img class="jwlogo" src="https://jackwhiteiii.com/wp-content/themes/lazaretto/images/JW_BHR_SplashPage_tiny.jpg" alt="Header Logo">
  </div>
</header>
<container>
  <div class="video">
    <iframe class="vevovideo" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8vKTaoxvZMY" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</container>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usual practise when you want to make responsive video (width 100% and height according to it) is to position it absolutely inside element with pseudo padding set according to aspect ratio of video.

Here is example:
https://codepen.io/crishpeen/pen/Pgvabw

I also added the logo and video to `.container` so it has same width.